# C++ Sort array of numeric strings - Compare function not working

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, numeric

I want to sort an array of numeric strings and I am using the sort() function from the C++ library.

I am passing to the function a third parameter to tell how to compare the strings but I can't get it right.

Can somebody help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

bool howToCompare(string i, string j) {
    if(i.length() > j.length()) {
        return i > j;
    }
    else if(i.length() < j.length()) {
        return i < j;
    }
    else {
        for(int k = 0; k < i.length(); k++) {
            if(i[k] - '0' < j[k] - '0') {
                return i < j;
            }
            else if (i[k] - '0' > j[k] - '0'){
                return i > j;
            }
        }
    }
    return i == j;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    string array[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    sort(array, array + n, howToCompare);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string array[n];` That's not standard c++. Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead please.

Comment: replace `i > j` to `false` and `i < j` to `true` in your `howToCompare` function

Comment: It worked by changing to true or false! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `howToCompare()` doesn't fit the requirements of [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) which expects to have a strict ordering.  The boolean that it returns should always correspond to the clause "less than".

Here a correction of your original code that works, assuming that the difference of length between two strings is nod caused by leading zeros:

```
bool howToCompare(string i, string j) {
    if(i.length() > j.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(i.length() < j.length()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for(int k = 0; k < i.length(); k++) {
            if(i[k]  < j[k] ) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (i[k]  > j[k] ){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/QBocY2) (you can also try your old function with some trace of what's going on on all the compares)

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/SiUGRB) that checks if strings are numeric only, that handles different size and potential leading 0, and uses a vector container instead of an array.